# Совместимость разных версий java

Tags: java

Приложения, скомпилированные на более старой версии jdk, будут ли гарантированно работать на машине с более новой версией jdk, или нет? И наоборот, приложения, скомпилированные на более новой версии jdk, будут ли гарантированно работать на машине с более старой версией jdk, или нет?

Comment: На второй вопрос ответ точно нет.

Comment: @Denis можно при компиляции указать в параметре `-target ` версию старой JVM, тогда будет.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, а это не является компиляцией _"на более старой версией jdk"_?. В смысле лямбды и дженерики для, например, v1,4 скомпилирует?

Comment: @Tachkin нет, конечно.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, тогда это просто компиляция под старой jdk. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У Java гарантирована бинарная совместимость снизу вверх. Т.е. код скомпилированный на более ранней версии будет работать на более поздней. Но есть некоторые несовместимости и они задокументированы.

При компиляции кода вы можете указать под какую версию вы компилируете. Т.е. используя компилятор 1.8 вы можете скомпилировать код под 1.6, но исходный код должен быть для 1.6.